# Как отключить отправку http-заголовка "Expires"?

Tags: http, битрикс

Прошу вас подсказать, как отключить отправку http-заголовка "Expires" (просто у меня есть подозрение, что код битрикса отправляет этот заголовок).

Comment: А для какого компонента выводится этот заголовок? Прямо на главной странице сайта или в каком-то разделе? Ссылку на сайт можно?

Comment: Компонент комплекcный news (bitrix:news.detail), 
например, вот эта страница - http://uenews.ru/content/news/92/2024/

Comment: > например, вот эта страница - http://uenews.ru/content/news/92/2024/

Я не нашел на этой странице тег, связанный с Expires

Comment: Плохо искали.

GET /content/news/92/2024/ HTTP/1.1
Host: uenews.ru

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.0.0
Date: Wed, 31 Aug 2011 07:03:28 GMT
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
...

Comment: извиняюсь! я думал про тэг <meta http-equiv="Expires" ...> который выводится на странице.

Comment: Тогда предлагаю, чтобы убедиться битрикс это отправляет заголовок или нет, поправить или закомментить строку № 122 в файле `/bitrix/modules/main/classes/general/cache_html.php`.

Answer (score 1):

Ну, не знаю, как в Битриксе, но на уровне веб-сервера можно отключить.
В апаче:

```
Header unset Expires
```

В nginx так:

```
more_clear_headers 'Expires';
```

Внимание, модуль не стандартный, в дистрибутив nginx не входит. Можно попробовать еще так:

```
add_header Expires "";
```

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы проверить, битрикс это или нет, попробуйте в файле **/bitrix/modules/main/classes/general/cache_html.php** закомментировать строку 122 **header("Expires:...**

Comment: интересно для чего это нужно битриксу?? (отправлять просроченный экспаирс)